# How to fix "Cannot import Lottery from brownie"?

Tags: solidity, brownie

Ran the code as shown and my constructor is public but I keep getting "Cannot import Lottery from brownie" as the error. The Lottery.sol code is below;

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract lottery {
    address payable[] public players;
    uint256 public usdEntryFee;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;

    constructor(address _priceFeedAddress) public {
        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        //$50 minimum
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        //
        (, int256 price, , , ) = ethUsdPriceFeed.latestRoundData();
        uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * 10**10;
        uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice;
        return costToEnter;
    }

    function startLottery() public {}

    function endLottery() public {}
}
```

The deploy.py code is below:

```
#0.0317789204065159
#310000000000000000
from brownie import Lottery, accounts, config, network
from web3 import Web3


def test_get_entrance_fee():
    account = accounts[0]
    lottery = lottery.deploy(
        config["networks"][network.showactive()]["eth_usd_price_feed"],
        {"from": account},
    )
    assert lottery.getEntranceFee() > Web3.toWei(0.028, "ether")
    assert lottery.getEntranceFee() < Web3.toWei(0.038, "ether")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written contract name `lottry` in small case.

Changes are to be done :

`from brownie import Lottery, accounts, config, network`

to

`from brownie import` **lottery** `, accounts, config, network`

Comment: I tried that already, same issue.

Comment: If you are trying to test. Check correct spelling in confest.py file also. 
It would be better if you could share all code through github

Comment: I actually tried what you mentioned initially again but this time I recompiled so right now I am battling another error, an attribute error. Says  AttributeError: 'ContractContainer' object has no attribute 'getEntranceFee' From the deploy.py code I initially posted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it was actually still the same issue of casing used. Thank you

Comment: Welcome. Try to give first letter as capital for Smart Contract name